# Why does my method inside a class only draw the first circle but if i just use filloval method inside a for loop it displays all circles?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm writing a program that displays a circle every time you click the Jpanel. I have it all set up and I want to be able to use the drawCircle method I created in my circle class to draw the circles in the paintComponent method. I'm storing all of the circles created in a linked list. Then I interate through each Circle in the list and try to use the method in my Circle class called drawCircle().

For some reason, if I try to use c1.drawCircle() in a for loop in the My panel class it only draws the last circle that was created. But if I just use g.fillOval(with the correct parameters grabbing the values from the Circle class) in the for loop it works properly and displays all the circles. Why is it doing this and how do I go about using the method in the Circle class properly

I'm unsure what to try right now.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MouseTest {
private int borderWidth = 20;
private JFrame frame;
private boolean tracking;
private boolean start;
private boolean clearBol;
private int xstart;
private int ystart;
private int xend;
private int yend;
private LinkedList<Circle> circles;


public MouseTest() {
    tracking = false;
    start = false;
    circles = new LinkedList<Circle>();
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(250, 98, 600, 480);
    frame.setTitle("Window number three");

    Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
    JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    JToggleButton circleButton = new JToggleButton()("Circles");
    JToggleButton drawButton = new JToggleButton("Draw");
    ButtonGroup circleOrDraw = new ButtonGroup();
    MyPanel pane = new MyPanel();

    clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            clearBol = true;
            frame.repaint();
        }
    });

    JPanel top = new JPanel();
    top.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    top.add(clear);
    circleOrDraw.add(circleButton);
    circleOrDraw.add(drawButton);
    top.add(circleOrDraw);
    cp.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    cp.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            xstart = e.getX();
            ystart = e.getY();
            start = false;


        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            xend = e.getX();
            yend = e.getY();

            if (xend < xstart) {
                int tmp = xstart;

                xstart = xend;
                xend = tmp;
            }

            if (yend < ystart) {
                int tmp = ystart;

                ystart = yend;
                yend = tmp;
            }
            start = true;
            frame.repaint();
        }
    });
    pane.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            if (tracking) {
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();

                msg("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
            }
        }
    });
    frame.setVisible(true);
}    // constructor

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    MouseTest first = new MouseTest();
}    // main

public void msg(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}

public void trackMouse() {
    tracking = !tracking;
}    // trackMouse

public class Circle extends JPanel {
    Graphics g;
    int x;
    int y;
    int r;
    Color color;

    public Circle(Graphics g, int x, int y, int r) {
        this.g = g;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
        int red = (int) (256 * Math.random());
        int green = (int) (256 * Math.random());
        int blue = (int) (256 * Math.random());
        this.color = new Color(red, green, blue);
    }

    public void drawCircle() {
        int x2 = x - (r / 2);
        int y2 = y - (this.r / 2);

        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x2, y2, this.r, this.r);


    }


    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }


}

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {


        if (start) {

            circles.add(new Circle(g, xend, yend,
                    (int) ((250 * Math.random() + 4))));

            //Area where I'm having issues
            for (Circle c1 : circles) {
                msg("" + c1.getX());
// this method that I created in the circle class will only draw the first circle

                //c1.drawCircle();  
                int r = c1.getR();
                int x = c1.getX();
                int y = c1.getY();

                g.setColor(c1.getColor());
                g.fillOval((c1.getX() - (r / 2)), (c1.getY() - (r / 2)),
                        r, r); // this will display all the circles
            }
            int size = circles.size();
            msg(size + " Size");


            msg("" + circles.getLast().getX());


        }
        if (clearBol) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            circles.clear();
            clearBol= false;


        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the value of `r` for those circles? The code that works uses hardcoded width and height of 40, the code that doesn't work uses each circle's radius. Is it possible that the circles are outside the visible area? That's the only difference I can spot. Anyways, I recommend you use your debugger to check what your code is doing: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173) Also please add a [MCVE], because with the code you posted we can only do guess work.

Comment: I don't know what your requirements are but it would be much simpler to have a circle class that simply stores the diameter, color, border color and thickness, and any other attributes.  Then you just need a `draw` method which takes a center point and a graphics context.  No need to extend JPanel.  You can even do a `mouseListener` to determine if the mouse is inside the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the structure of your class needs to be changed

1. Your MyPanel should have a better name to give its functionality, maybe something like `DrawingPanel`.
2. The `DrawingPanel` is then responsible for managing the Circles to be painted. So typically you would just use an ArrayList to hold the Circle information.
3. Then you would add a method to the class, like `addCircle(...)` to add the Circle information to the ArrayList and then invoke repaint().
4. Then in your `paintComponent(...)` method the first thing you do is invoke super.paintComponent(...) to clear the panel. Then you iterate through the ArrayList and paint all the Circles. There will be no need for the Boolean values to check the state of the class. The ArrayList will either have circles or it won't.
5. You would also need a method like `clearCircles()`. This would simply remove all the Circles from the ArrayList and invoke repaint() on itself.
6. Your `Circle` class should NOT extend JPanel. It should just be a class that contains the information need to paint the circle: x/y location, size of circle and color of circle.
7. Now your frame is responsible of displaying your `DrawingPanel` and the buttons.
8. When you click the "Clear" button you simply invoke the `clearCircles()` method of the `DrawingPanel`.
9. For your MouseListener you simply invoke the `addCircle(...)` method of your `DrawingPanel` once you have all the information needed to create a Circle instance.

For a complete working example that incorporates all these suggestions check out the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/)