# Passing circle objects to an Arraylist after drawing them

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

/*  Hello I am working on this program that requires me to draw circles on a Jpanel using the PaintComponent method.

So far my circles show up, but I need to keep track of them, so I've decided to use an Arraylist to add them. With every mouse click, a new circle appears, but my Arraylist only shows me the current circle object and not the previous object after a new click. I've already looked at similar questions on here, but nothing seems to work for me, next is my code so far*/

```
        pane_main.add(myCircle,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        myCircle.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                xstart= e.getX();
                ystart = e.getY();
                radius = (int) (Math.random()*100);
                frame1.repaint();
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
                xend = e.getX();
                yend = e.getY();
                if (xend < xstart) { int tmp = xstart; xstart = xend; xend = tmp; }
                if (yend < ystart) { int tmp = ystart; ystart = yend; yend = tmp; }
                Circle cr = new Circle(xcenter,ycenter,radius);
                circleList.add(cr);//adding to list
            }
        });
        myCircle.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){

           public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
                if (Trackmouse){
                    int x = e.getX();
                    int y = e.getY();
                    printMsg("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
                }
           }

        });
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }
//the class that has paint component
  public class Circle extends JPanel {
        public Circle(){
        }
        public Circle(int x,int y,int radius){
        }
        public int getCenterX(){
            return xstart - radius;
        }
        public int getCenterY(){
            return ystart - radius;
        }
        public int getRadius(){
            return radius;
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int red     = (int)(256*Math.random());
            int green   = (int)(256*Math.random());
            int blue    = (int)(256*Math.random());
            int width  = this.getWidth();
            int height = this.getHeight();
            printMsg("H = " + height + ",  w = " + width);
                for (Circle circle: circleList){
                    int count = 1;
                    g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
                    printMsg("Colors are:  " + red + " - " + green + " - " + blue );
                    g.fillOval(getCenterX(),getCenterY(),getRadius() *2,getRadius() *2);
                    System.out.println("For circle object " + count + ": ");
                    System.out.println("Center coordinates are: (" + circle.getCenterX() + " ," + circle.getCenterY()+ " )");
                    System.out.println("Radius is: " + circle.getRadius());
                    ++ count ;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

/* 
    H = 405,  w = 584
    Colors are:  17 - 96 - 230
    For circle object 1: 
    Center coordinates are: (202 ,94 )
    Radius is: 25
    H = 405,  w = 584
    Colors are:  78 - 137 - 123
    For circle object 1: 
    Center coordinates are: (97 ,289 )
    Radius is: 5
    Colors are:  78 - 137 - 123
    For circle object 1: 
    Center coordinates are: (97 ,289 )
    Radius is: 5
    Here is a sample output from running it, the first time the radius of the circle was 25, the second time the radius is 5 but it displays that result twice instead of the previous and current, any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks! */

Comment: *I've already looked at similar questions on here,* - then how did you miss this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001759/why-does-my-method-inside-a-class-only-draw-the-first-circle-but-if-i-just-use-f/58002489#58002489 which was just asked yesterday? The suggestions there apply to your code as well. The structure of your code is wrong and needs to be fixed.